# Uncaught TypeError: $(...) in laravel mix

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

current set up my webpack.mix.js in the following way:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And scripts:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.dynamicmaxheight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and **app.js** is

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

also **bootstrap.js** is

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}
```

for top codes, everything works fine.

---

Now I want merge all script file in one file.

so I've set up my webpack.mix.js in the following way:

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js',
        'resources/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
        'resources/assets/js/jquery.isotope.js',
        'resources/assets/js/wow.js',
        'resources/assets/js/classie.js',
        'resources/assets/js/jquery.dynamicmaxheight.js',
        'resources/assets/js/slick.js',
        'resources/assets/js/sweetalert2.all.min.js'
      ], 'public/js/main.js')
      .autoload({
      jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
      })
      .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
      .styles([
        'resources/assets/css/slick.css',
        'resources/assets/css/slick-theme.css',
        'resources/assets/css/responsive.css',
        'resources/assets/css/animate.min.css',
        'resources/assets/css/sweetalert2.min.css'
      ],'resources/assets/css/style.css')
      .combine(['public/css/app.css','resources/assets/css/style.css'], 'public/css/main.css');
```

and script section in html doc:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

and app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('sweetalert');
```

and bootstrap.js with no change.

with `npm run dev`, it build successful but plugins not works.

I get like these error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dynamicmaxheight is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).wow is not a function

Comment: try `mix.scripts([` instead of `mix.js([`. From docs [Laravel Mix - Vanilla JS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#vanilla-js) __combine and minify any number of JavaScript files with the scripts() method__

Comment: Also, useful [mix wiki](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs#readme)